# $apply vs $digest in directive testing

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

If I have a directive that responds to the status of a particular attribute on the scope, and I want to change that attribute in my test and verify that it responds correctly, which is the best way of doing that change?

I've seen both these patterns:

```
scope.$apply(function() {
    scope.myAttribute = true;
});
```

and

```
scope.myAttribute = true;
scope.$digest();
```

What is the difference between them, and which is better and why?

Answer (score 207, accepted):

`scope.$digest()` will fire watchers on the current scope, and on all of its children, too. `scope.$apply` will evaluate passed function and run `$rootScope.$digest()`.

The first one is faster, as it needs to evaluate watchers for current scope and its children. The second one is slower, as it needs to evaluate watchers for`$rootScope` and all it's child scopes.

When an error occurs in one of the watchers and you use `scope.$digest`, it's not handled via `$exceptionHandler` service, so you need to handle exception yourself. `scope.$apply` uses a `try-catch` block internally and passes all exceptions to `$exceptionHandler`.

Comment: Will `$digest` also be called on the scope's children?

Comment: This can be misleading. `$digest` does not only fire watchers on current scope, but on all of its children too.

Comment: @tasseKATT, I think I've captured what your comment is suggesting.

Answer (score 12):

As the documentation itself mentions $digest cycle is peformed any time you do `$scope.$apply`.  As per developer guide on [scope](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope)

> After evaluating the expression, the $apply method performs a $digest.
>   In the $digest phase the scope examines all of the $watch expressions
>   and compares them with the previous value.

And as per the Scope API [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope)

> Usually you don't call $digest() directly in controllers or in
>   directives. Instead a call to $apply() (typically from within a
>   directives) will force a $digest().

So you should not explicitly call `$digest`, you calling `$apply` method would trigger a digest cycle.

Comment: this is not true as digest is sufficient for most of the cases where only the current scope and its children need to be evaluated. it is true that $scope.$apply calls $digest internally but it is very important to remember it will end up calling $rootScope.$digest() and hence very heavy