# How does AngularJS know when variables change? How does AngularJS dirty checking work?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, observer-pattern

I was reading some article to understand a little bit more how AngularJS works.

One of the terms that I didn't understand is `Dirty Checking`.

What is it exactly? It seems like the Observer pattern but apparently it's better.

Can you help me understand this please?

EDIT : it can be also useful for people who wants to learn more about that to watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mk2WwSxK218) from [swiip](https://github.com/Swiip) at NgEurope some years ago.

Comment: Maybe this article will help: http://blog.bguiz.com/post/57373805814/accessors-vs-dirty-checking-in-javascript-frameworks/

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/

Answer (score 57, accepted):

From [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112584/using-scope-watch-and-scope-apply/15113029#15113029):

> Angular defines a concept of a so called digest
>   cycle. This cycle can be considered as a loop, during which Angular
>   checks if there are any changes to all the variables watched by all
>   the $scopes. So if you have $scope.myVar defined in your controller
>   and this variable was marked for being watched, then you are
>   explicitly telling Angular to monitor the changes on myVar in each
>   iteration of the loop.

This "`digest`" is also called "dirty checking", because, in a way, it *scans* the scope for changes. I cannot say if it's for better or for worse than observable pattern. It depends on your needs.

Some links:

- [Angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#scope-life-cycle)
- [A blog post about Angular scopes](http://blog.ponyfoo.com/2014/02/14/angle-brackets-rifle-scopes)

Answer (score 19):

Angular Dirty Checking mechanism workflow.

[image]

> Dirty checking is a simple process that boils down to a very basic
>   concept: It checks whether a value has changed that hasn’t yet been
>   synchronized across the app.
>
> Our Angular app keeps track of the values of the current watches.
>   Angular walks down the
>   $watch list, and, if the updated value has not changed from the old
>   value, it continues down the list. If the value has changed, the app
>   records the new value and continues down the $watch list.

[**Check out the whole article here**](https://www.ng-book.com/p/The-Digest-Loop-and-apply/)

Comment: Is this for Angular or Angular JS ? What is done in Angular pls ?

Answer (score 7):

**What is dirty checking?**

The process of checking every watch to detect the changes, is called dirty checking. There could be two scenarios

**First –**

1. Get a watch from list
2. Check whether item has been changed
3. If there is no change in item then
4. No Action taken, move to next item in watch list

**Second–**

1. Get a watch from list
2. Check whether item has been changed
3. If there is Change in an item
4. DOM needs to be updated, return to digest loop

*In second case, loop continues till it finds no changes in the entire loop. And once it completes, DOM gets updated if required.*

Answer (score 4):

Just modifying a previous answer...

Angular has a concept of **‘digest cycle’**. You can consider it as a loop. In which Angular checks if there are any changes to all the variables watched by all the `$scope`s (*internally `$watch()` and `$apply()` functions are getting bonded with each variable defined under `$scope`*).

So if you have `$scope.myVar` defined in your controller (that means this variable `myVar` was marked for being watched) then you are explicitly telling Angular to monitor the changes on `myVar` in each iteration of the loop. So when the value of `myVar` changes, every time `$watch()` notices and execute `$apply()` to apply the changes in DOM.

This "**Digest**" is also called "**dirty checking**", because, in a way, it scans the scope for changes. As all watched variable are in a single loop (digest cycle), any value change of any variable forces to reassign values of other watched variables in DOM.

**PROS:** This is the way Angular achieves Two-way data binding.

**CONS:** If there are more watched variables in a single page (>2000–3000), you may see lag while page loading. (But I say if there are that many ‘watched variables’ in a single page, it is a bad page design :p).

There are other cons, as well as are workarounds also :D

Answer (score 2):

Dirty checking
will check anything changes in $scope variable and update it to the DOM.
This done by angular js, you can also implement dirty checking by your own.

Answer (score 2):

I read a great article about dirty checking in [this blog post](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/). There was also  this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18697745/apply-vs-digest-in-directive-testing)

**TLDR; version**

When the $digest cycle kicks in, the watchers will check for any changes in the scope model and if there are any (the change might also come from out-of-Angular-domain), the corresponding listener functions are executed. This will again run the $digest loop and checks if the scope model was changed (the listener function could also modify the scope model).

Overall, the $digest cycle will run twice even if the listener does not change the model or till it hits the max loop count of 10.