# Why is the interpolation expression executed multiple times?

Tags: angular

It's a simple Angular4 application.
I am calling a method using interpolation. It's getting executed 4 times.

*app.component.ts*

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 1;



 testing(){
     console.log('IN testing 0');

 }

 private testing1(){
    console.log('IN testing 1');
 }
}
```

*app.component.html*

```
<h2>{{testing1()}}</h2>
<button (click)="testing()">Testing2 </button>
```

When the page is loaded it prints "IN testing 1" 4 times. When I click the button it prints "IN testing 1" twice. I am not able to understand the flow.

Comment: here's a [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24698620/dirty-checking-on-angular) to help you understand the digest cycle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you call function like this `<h2>{{testing1()}}</h2>` in each change detection `testing1()` function will get triggered. that is why its printing console multiple time. This is a bad habit. instead of using a function use a variable