# ReactJS virtual DOM in memory and applying incremental changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

Came across below [statement](https://www.accelebrate.com/blog/the-real-benefits-of-the-virtual-dom-in-react-js/) in one or other form on google

> Each time the underlying data changes in a React app, a new Virtual
>   DOM representation of the user interface is created.This is where
>   things get interesting. Updating the browser’s DOM is a three-step
>   process in React.
>
> 1. Whenever anything may have changed, the entire UI will be re-rendered
>      in a Virtual DOM representation.
> 2. The difference between the previous
>      Virtual DOM representation and the new one will be calculated.
> 3. The
>      real DOM will be updated with what has actually changed. This is very
>      much like applying a patch.

I am new to React and would like to understand above how above three points used to to work in pre-React Era say in jQuery (or native JS).

jQuery

1. HTML was constructed on server side, sent back to browser. Browser will parse, render, layout and paint it.
2. Say any new DOM element is created or hidden either on some user event or on load.
3. Will jQuery recreate the complete DOM? From third point stated above looks like React just update the DOM for only the part that has been changed but other system (primarily jQuery or native JS) will recreate the complete DOM. Is that correct?
4. Is the third point true only for DOM changes or even when state of any UI component changes like filling the text box/dropdown etc?

Comment: yeah, the simplest way was to replace `innerHTML` of a container with a current version. But this was problematic because DOM is stateful and *slow*.

Comment: No jQuery will not recreate the complete DOM. Only parts you change. I think for a fair comparison you should compare React to libraries like knockout or angular when it comes to DOM updates based on data updates. In jQuery you need to do all of these manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Will jquery recreate the complete DOM ? From third point stated above looks like React just update the DOM for only the part that has been changed but other system(primarily jquery or native js) will recreate the complete DOM. Is that correct?**

**jQuery**

---

No, jQuery doesn't recreate the DOM. Instead it navigates the DOM tree with selectors provided to make the appropriate changes. This makes jQuery very similar to React, but its performance issues come with the way the code was designed and it's heavy usage of the [facade design pattern](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/facade-design-pattern-introduction/). This is normal for any larger library that needs to support multiple browsers like Chrome, Firefox, Opera, etc.

**Angular 1**

---

A framework that used to repaint the entire DOM was Angular 1. The client would make some changes, and rerender whenever `$scope.apply` or `$scope.digest` was called. This, combined with a huge number of listeners on large pages for two way data-binding was one of the big reasons why Angular had to undergo significant changes to stay competitive. Angular 8 is probably equivalent to React, but one has seen more adoption then the other.

**React**

---

React only updates the DOM that was changed. This is part of its "secret sauce". Along with its component centric architecture and early adoption of one way data-binding, it's seen a lot of success. Arguably React is starting to get more bloated since there's such wide adoption. This is normal for any project that gets mainstream usage. It's only a matter of time until people view React as a ton of performance problems and we'll create a new framework.

**Alternatives**

---

There are even faster frameworks than React, such as [Elm lang](https://elm-lang.org). Nothing ever beats pure Javascript (e.g. `document.querySelector()`) since at their core, all frameworks use it. At that point you start hitting other trade offs such as lack of external libraries you can depend on, or difficulty in maintaining large front end codebases.

---

**Is the third point true only for dom changes or even when state of any UI component changes like filling the text box/drop down etc ?**

For jQuery or pure JS the third point is not true. There's a custom `on-click` handler of some sort that will run a function that makes a small change.

For something like Angular, that could be true if there are changes to `scope` that trigger a repaint. The same applies for React. If your `submit` button is supposed to redirect you to a completely different page, it will basically be repainting the DOM.

Comment: Thanks Joseph. Two follow up questions. In Angular , if there is addition/removal of DOM element happens, complete DOM gets repainted(probably along with re-layout) but in react only that particular section gets  painted ? Second question: On filling the value in text box, Angular scope changes and it does complete DOM repaint, React only does that specific section repaint(probably jquery is also similar) . Right ?

Comment: To your first question, yes. To your second question, also yes. Please keep in mind this is Angular 1 many many moons ago. I can't speak for later versions of Angular but I'm confident they do something very similar to React now. I found a good link if you are curious: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41972620/4842949

Comment: Thanks Joseph. Apologise for accepting the answer so late as I was out of office