# Why is DOM not updated by $scope change inside `keydown` function in Angular

Tags: angularjs

Based on below controller, I think the `<div>` with `ngShow` should appear when the `left` keyboard arrow is pressed.

The `$scope` **does** update (which can be seen as its printed to console) but the DOM doesn't change.

But when i type something into the `input` field, the `<div>` then appears. So its like angular is not watching for changes I'm making with `keydown`.

**Controller**

```
.controller('TestCtrl', ['$scope', '$document', function($scope, $document) {
    var keyboardMap = { 37: 'left'};
    $document.on('keydown', function (event) {
        var key = keyboardMap[event.which];
        if (key) {
            console.log('lefty');
            $scope.left = true;
        } 
    });
}]);
```

**View**

```
<div ng-app="TestApp" ng-controller="TestCtrl">
    <div ng-show="left" style="height: 100px; width: 100px; border: 1px black solid;"></div>
    <input ng-model="something"></input>
</div>
```

I read a few other similar question on SO but didn't find them helpful. I do feel like theres something I don't understand here though.

Does anyone know why its not updating, and how I could make it update?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please execute `$digest()` as AngularJS doesn't know anything about `on` event.

```js
function TestCtrl($scope, $document) {
  $document.on('keydown', function(event) {
    var keyboardMap = {
      37: 'left'
    };
    var key = keyboardMap[event.which];
    if (key) {
      $scope.left = true;
      $scope.$digest()
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app ng-controller="TestCtrl">
  <div ng-show="left" style="height: 100px; width: 100px; border: 1px black solid;"></div>
  <input ng-model="something">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your code in a `$apply` block:

```
if (key) {
            console.log('lefty');
            $scope.$apply(function() {
                $scope.left = true;
            });
        }
```

This forces model updates from events from the outside of angulars world. [Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply)

**Edit:** `$scope.$digest()` is another way to do this. [Read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18697745/apply-vs-digest-in-directive-testing) for an explanation of the differences.